# IE 11 equivalent to Firefox's site certification exception?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I am going to a HTTPS site and in IE 11 I get the error "This site is not secure", I can then click "More information" and then continue to the web page but this is annoying to do every time I go to the site.

When I first went to it in Fire Fox I was able to add an exception and don't get it anymore. Unfortunately the site does not work in Firefox and I have to use IE so I have been trying to find a similar function to the "add exception" option but unable to.

Is there a way in IE 11 to get it to stop complaining about the site not being secure like I can in Firefox?

Comment: Yes; Add the invalid certificate to the user's certificate store.  Firefox uses its own certificate store, which is what the exception process does, you add the invalid certificate to the Firefox certificate store

Comment: @Ramhound But how do I add the cert?

Comment: The process of adding the certificate to the user's certificate store is documented.  Have you researched how to do that?